# Conditional assignment in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm working on a project with several instances of the following pattern that I am not familiar with.  I don't know what to call it so I can't find any docs on it.  What is the following concept?

```
if !@two = [nil, 2].sample
  puts 'there was an error'
else
  puts @two
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Do try and avoid double negatives. Flipping this to a positive test and reversing the order of the `puts` statements would make this a lot more sensible. If you're not careful you can end up with triple and quadruple negatives that are real head-spinners.

Comment: This is awful code. Further to @tadman's comment, isn't this a lot clearer: `@two = [nil, 2].sample; puts @two ? @two : "there was an error"`.

Comment: Even better would be to write a method like `def coin_flip; [ :heads, :tails ].sample; end` and then `if (coin_flip == :heads)` which conveys more of what's going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It basically leans on Ruby's *falsy* objects: `nil` and `false`.

Everything except for `nil` and `false` is said to be *truthy* in Ruby.

So in the example it prints the value of `@two` if it's *truthy* (2), otherwise (`nil`) it prints the error message.

I do not think this "concept" has a name.

Comment: "If it's truthy..."  Does that mean if the right side of the assignment is truthy?

Comment: @JoeEssey you assing `@two` in both cases. It is the matter of the assigned value - truthy one (`2`) or falsy (`nil`)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing special here, it's equivalent to:

```
@two = [nil, 2].sample

if !@two
  puts 'there was an error'
else
  puts @two
end
```

`@two = [nil, 2].sample` returns a random element from `[nil, 2]`, i.e. either `nil` or `2`, and assigns it to the instance variable `@two`.

The conditional should be self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

The practice of using the value of an assignment expression in a conditional doesn't really have a *name*, per se, but the practice of wrapping the assignment in parenthesis is called ["Safe assignment in condition"](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#safe-assignment-in-condition), which is something you should adopt if you're writing code like this.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  I tested it and it worked, but it seemed just off.  Nice to see the style guide addresses this.